# The process of Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing

OK, I know what a unit test is but I use it in some projects and not others...some clients don't know how its done and follow one convention...blah blah.

so here I am asking, how EXACTLY is a unit test process created? 
I hear, and read, that you write the tests first then the functionality and write the tests for that functionality and also use code coverage to identify any "slips" of not having tests for that code which has not been covered.

So, lets use a simple example:

Requirement: "application must return the result of 2 numbers combined."

you and I know we would have a class, something like "Addition" and a method "Add" which returns an integer like so:

```
public class Addition
{
   public int Add(int num1, int num2)
   {
      return num1 + num2;
   }
}
```

But even before writing this class, how do you write tests first? What is your process? What do you do? What would the process be when you have that spec doc and going into development?

Many thanks,

Comment: You'll get more responses on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Process you're referring to is called [Test-Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). Idea is simple and close to what you described; given functionality, you start writing code by writing test for this functionality. In your add example, **before** any working code is written you should have a simple test - a test that fails.

### Failing Test

```
[Test]
public void TestAdd()
{
     var testedClass = new Addition();

     var result = testedClass.Add(1, 2);

     Assert.AreEqual(result, 3);
}
```

This is a simple test for your `.Add` method, stating your expectations of the soon-to-be working code. Since you don't have any code just yet, this test will naturally fail (as it is supposed to - which is good).

### Passing test

Next step is to write **the most basic** code that makes the test pass (*naturally, the most basic code is `return 3;` but for this simple example this level of details is not necessary*):

```
public int Add(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

This works and test passes. What you have at this point, is basic proof that your method works in the way you stated it in your assumptions/expectations (the test).

However, you might notice that this test is not a good one; it tests only one simple input data of many. Not to mention, in some cases one test might not be enough and even though you had initial requirements, testing might reveal more is needed (for example arguments validation or logging). This is the part when you go back to reviewing your requirements and writing tests, which leads us to...

### Refactor

At this point you should [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) code you just wrote. And I'm talking **both** unit test methods code and tested implementation. Since `Add` method is fairly simple and there's not much you can improve in terms of adding two numbers, you can focus on making test better. For example:

- add more test cases (or consider data driven testing)
- make test name more descriptive
- improve variables naming
- extract magic numbers to constants

Like this:

```
[TestCase(0, 0, 0)]
[TestCase(1, 2, 3)]
[TestCase(1, 99, 100)]
public void Add_ReturnsSumOfTwoNumbers(int first, int second, int expectedSum)
{
     var testedClass = new Addition();

     var actualSum = testedClass.Add(first, second);

     Assert.That(actualSum, Is.EqualTo(expectedSum));
}
```

Refactoring is topic worth it's own book (and there are many), so I won't go into details. The process we just went through is often referred to as ***Red-Green-Refactor*** (red indicating failing test, green - passing one), and it's part of TDD. Remember to rerun the test one more time in order to make sure refactoring didn't accidentally break anything.

This is how the basic cycle goes. You start with requirements, write failing test for it, write code to make test pass, refactor **both code and tests**, review requirements, proceed with next task.

### Where to go from here?

Few useful resources that are good natural follow-up once you get to know the idea behind TDD (even from such brief explanation as presented in this post):

- [Test-Driven Development by example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) - introduction to TDD by [Kent Beck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck) himself
- [Test-Driven Development in Microsoft.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619484) - this book is great walkthrough especially if you're new to TDD. It explains concepts really well and contains comprehensive example of application development with TDD (including data access, web services and more)
- [Roy Osherove's TDD Kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) - contains videos of people developing simple calculator API with TDD; many different languages, many different frameworks (definitely worth seeing)

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I know about refactoring, best practices etc... but TDD is one thing i need to improve on and become an expert in if possible. Now, here is the thing: we have a requirement. We create the class and a very basic method. In this method to test, what kind of code should be there? Obviously not real functionality but what instead? Please feel free to use a more complicated and real example.

Comment: @Ahmed Think what each method should do. Give examples of inputs and related outputs. Then check that given the inputs the method produces the outputs. Consider testing some simple normal cases, any border cases, possibly error handling.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: the basic *non-working* version of tested method usually throws exception - in .NET, that would be `NotImplementedException` or `InvalidOperationException`. I've added links to few resources - I especially suggest you check TDD Kata videos - lot of examples how people do TDD on well defined task.